# laravel command not found while using laravel command

Tags: php, laravel, installation, command

I've recently installed composer and also installed laravel installer from composer from the commmand line just like they said in [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) documentation.
But when I used the laravel command on the command line, it show error:

```
sh.exe": laravel: command not found
```

I also added environment variable in the path variable.

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

But still the same error occurs while using the laravel command. 
I'm a laravel newbie and I'm stuck in laravel installation.I've searched lot of times but still could not get the solution. I've read lot of users' questions with the same problem and used their solutions but still could not fix this.

Comment: show your `$PATH` output

Comment: /c/xampp/php:~/.composer/vendor/bin

Comment: do you see laravel in that path? I do agree with @Koga

Comment: I've copy-pasted the exact location of the file and echoing the $PATH variable shows the exact same location. But still won't let that command.

Comment: No, there's no 'laravel' in that path..

Comment: Then it doesn't work for obvious reasons. you need to add the path of the location where that file is

Comment: `C:\Users\Birendra Gurung\AppData\Roaming\.Composer\vendor\bin` this is my current path set to the variable and I've checked the location. Is it correct to place a ` .  `  before the composer folder name?

Comment: Yeah, that means, `composer` folder is hidden. It is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows system, please remove `.` from path (just before `.Composer`)

Answer (score 6):

Your path `/c/xampp/php:~/.composer/vendor/bin` is definitly wrong. Either you have to fix it (should be something like `C:/{path_to_your_composer_directory}`) or you can simply use `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` to install a new laravel project.

I would go with the 2nd option, because you don't have to configure something else.

Comment: I've add the exact same location on the environment variable but still the same error is shown. The second option would be great if there's no need for the `laravel` command any more in further development using the framework. Any way worked out the second way.